# Missing array element

Tags: php, arrays, session

So, I have `view.php` file in which I use `$_SESSION` variable:

`$_SESSION["test"] = 'background-color: #100D0D;';`

And when I passing it to another page - it actually works

```
$backColor = $_SESSION["test"];
```

But, when it passing `test` variable with array element:

```
$_SESSION["test"] = 'background-color: '.strtoupper($atts['background_color']);
```

On the first page (where I initialized this variable) it works perfect and gets a value, which I expected, however on the second page, where we have variable `$backColor` in which I passed `$test` variable - I get only `background-color:`part without saved HEX-colour code.

The most strange thing - that on the first page I get all part of string (including HEX-code), but on the second one my HEX-code is 'gone'.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Looks like ur re assigning $_SESSION['test'] on the second page where $atts is not set

Comment: @Sebastian the problem is - that array is visible on the first page (so I initialize  `test` variable properly ) but when I pass already initialized value - it is gone .So,do I have to initialize this array also in the second page or what?

Comment: You should not re initialize $_SESSION's variable on the second page

Comment: On the second page I just initialize `$backColor` varaible with `$_SESSION` variable . (The third line of code - it is just a variant of initializing `test` variable on the first page

Comment: There is no way hex color disappears from a string in SESSION , turn on error reporting on your site and you will see where the overwrite occurs as it is using most likely an undefined variable

Comment: What is `$atts` ?

Comment: and why do you store a css in the session and not the class name?

Comment: and why do you use such a logic in a view? rethink your design.